# How do you create merge_asof functionality in PySpark?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Table `A` has many columns with a date column, Table `B` has a datetime and a value. The data in both tables are generated sporadically with no regular interval. Table `A` is small, table `B` is massive.

I need to join `B` to `A` under the condition that a given element `a` of `A.datetime` corresponds to

```
B[B['datetime'] <= a]]['datetime'].max()
```

There are a couple ways to do this, but I would like the most efficient way.

### Option 1

Broadcast the small dataset as a Pandas DataFrame. Set up a Spark UDF that creates a pandas DataFrame for each row merges with the large dataset using `merge_asof`.

### Option 2

Use the broadcast join functionality of Spark SQL: set up a theta join on the following condition

```
B['datetime'] <= A['datetime']
```

Then eliminate all the superfluous rows.

Option B seems pretty terrible... but please let me know if the first way is efficient or if there is another way.

**EDIT:** Here is the sample input and expected output:

```
A =
+---------+----------+
| Column1 | Datetime |
+---------+----------+
|    A    |2019-02-03|
|    B    |2019-03-14|
+---------+----------+

B =
+---------+----------+
|   Key   | Datetime |
+---------+----------+
|    0    |2019-01-01|
|    1    |2019-01-15|
|    2    |2019-02-01|
|    3    |2019-02-15|
|    4    |2019-03-01|
|    5    |2019-03-15|
+---------+----------+

custom_join(A,B) =
+---------+----------+
| Column1 |   Key    |
+---------+----------+
|    A    |     2    |
|    B    |     4    |
+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Table A is small with many columns? could you please post a sample for both the dataframes and also your expected output. Thanks

Comment: @vikrantrana See edit

Comment: Did you make any progress with that other than the helper function below? If not, can you provide the full code of the logic you use as helper function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### Anyone trying to do this in pyspark 3.x can use

[applyInPandas](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.PandasCogroupedOps.applyInPandas.html)

```
#### For Example:

  from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row, DataFrame
  import pandas as pd
  spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate()

  df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
      [(20000101, 1, 1.0), (20000101, 2, 2.0), (20000102, 1, 3.0), (20000102, 2, 4.0)],
      ("time", "id", "v1"))
  df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
      [(20000101, 1, "x"), (20000101, 2, "y")],
      ("time", "id", "v2"))
  def asof_join(l, r):
      return pd.merge_asof(l, r, on="time", by="id")
  df1.groupby("id").cogroup(df2.groupby("id")).applyInPandas(
      asof_join, schema="time int, id int, v1 double, v2 string"
  ).show()


  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  +--------+---+---+---+
  |    time| id| v1| v2|
  +--------+---+---+---+
  |20000101|  1|1.0|  x|
  |20000102|  1|3.0|  x|
  |20000101|  2|2.0|  y|
  |20000102|  2|4.0|  y|
  +--------+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 4):

You could solve it with Spark by using `union` and `last` together with a `window` function. Ideally you have something to partition your window by.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df1 = df1.withColumn('Key', f.lit(None))
df2 = df2.withColumn('Column1', f.lit(None))

df3 = df1.unionByName(df2)

w = Window.orderBy('Datetime', 'Column1').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)
df3.withColumn('Key', f.last('Key', True).over(w)).filter(~f.isnull('Column1')).show()
```

Which gives

```
+-------+----------+---+
|Column1|  Datetime|Key|
+-------+----------+---+
|      A|2019-02-03|  2|
|      B|2019-03-14|  4|
+-------+----------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a fast (but perhaps not the most efficient) method to complete this. I built a helper function:

```
def get_close_record(df, key_column, datetime_column, record_time):
    """
    Takes in ordered dataframe and returns the closest 
    record that is higher than the datetime given.
    """
    filtered_df = df[df[datetime_column] >= record_time][0:1]
    [key] = filtered_df[key_column].values.tolist()
    return key
```

Instead of joining `B` to `A`, I set up a `pandas_udf` of the above code and ran it on the columns of table `B` then ran `groupBy` on `B` with primary key `A_key` and aggregated `B_key` by `max`.

The issue with this method is that it requires monotonically increasing keys in `B`.

**Better solution:**

I developed the following helper function that should work

```
other_df['_0'] = other_df['Datetime']
bdf = sc.broadcast(other_df)

#merge asof udf
@F.pandas_udf('long')
def join_asof(v, other=bdf.value):
    f = pd.DataFrame(v)
    j = pd.merge_asof(f, other, on='_0', direction = 'forward')
    return j['Key']

joined = df.withColumn('Key', join_asof(F.col('Datetime')))
```

Comment: Does the better solution approach load the data into the driver program?