# grouping pyspark rows based on condtion

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this table with 6 columns and I want to group the rows by 'ID1' and 'ID2' based on the 'record' filed. My record fields are either 'IN' or 'OUT' and they are ordered by date.

Here is my input sample...

```
data = [("ACC.PXP","7246","2020-02-24T14:49:00",None,None,'IN'),
    ("ACC.PXP","7246","2021-03-09T08:20:00","Hospital","Foundation","OUT"),
    ("ACC.PXP","7246","2021-04-05T17:17:00","Hospital","Foundation","IN")
       ] 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=['ID1','ID2','date','type','name','record'])
df.show(truncate=False)

+-------+----+-------------------+--------+----------+------+
|ID1    |ID2 |date               |type    |name      |record|
+-------+----+-------------------+--------+----------+------+
|ACC.PXP|7246|2020-02-24T14:49:00|null    |null      |IN    |
|ACC.PXP|7246|2021-03-09T08:20:00|Hospital|Foundation|OUT   |
|ACC.PXP|7246|2021-04-05T17:17:00|Hospital|Foundation|IN    |
```

and here is what I want as a result

```
data2 = [("ACC.PXP","7246","2020-02-24T14:49:00",None,None, "2021-03-09T08:20:00","Hospital","Foundation"),
    ("ACC.PXP","7246","2021-04-05T17:17:00","Hospital","Foundation", None,None,None)
  ]
 
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=['ID1','ID2','date','type','name','date1','type1','name1'])
df2.show(truncate=False)

+-------+----+-------------------+--------+----------+-------------------+--------+----------+
|ID1    |ID2 |date               |type    |name      |date1              |type1   |name1     |
+-------+----+-------------------+--------+----------+-------------------+--------+----------+
|ACC.PXP|7246|2020-02-24T14:49:00|null    |null      |2021-03-09T08:20:00|Hospital|Foundation|
|ACC.PXP|7246|2021-04-05T17:17:00|Hospital|Foundation|null               |null    |null      |
+-------+----+-------------------+--------+----------+-------------------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: @sammywemmy do you have an idea on how to approach this?

Comment: Hi @ScootCork I saw your answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57435858/how-do-you-create-merge-asof-functionality-in-pyspark and my question resembles your answer. Do you think you can help with this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can group by ids and "count" and pivot "record" column as follows:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy("ID1", "ID2", "record").orderBy("date")
df1 = (df
   .withColumn("count", F.row_number().over(w))
   .groupBy("ID1", "ID2", "count")
   .pivot("record")
   .agg(F.first("date"), F.first( "type"), F.first("name"))
   .select("ID1", "ID2", 
           F.col("IN_first(date)").alias("date"),  
           F.col("IN_first(type)").alias("type"), 
           F.col("IN_first(name)").alias("name"),
           F.col("OUT_first(date)").alias("date1"),
           F.col("OUT_first(date)").alias("type1"),
           F.col("OUT_first(name)").alias("name1"))
  )
```

This will produce the required output table. However, just a warning that same as your solution, this solution assumes  that for each ID pair, the first dated entry is for record=IN, and that the rows follow IN-OUT-IN-OUT... sequence if ordered by date. Otherwise, this solution will not work correctly.

Comment: Hi @Anna, your code works fine for IN-ONT-IN... sequence when ordered by date. But what if I had bad data and the first record starts from OUT and I want to do the same thing as before. 

say my input is: 
```
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure someone will come up with a faster, shorter, and elegant pyspark code. But this one works as well.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
data = [("ACC.PXP","7246","2020-02-24T14:49:00",None,None,'IN'),
    ("ACC.PXP","7246","2021-03-09T08:20:00","Hospital","Foundation","OUT"),
    ("ACC.PXP","7246","2021-04-05T17:17:00","Hospital","Foundation","IN")
       ] 
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=['ID1','ID2','date','type','name','record'])
sdf.show(truncate=False)

## split the data frame into two based on record type and give it a one 
sdf_1 = sdf.filter("record == 'IN'").withColumn('ones', F.lit(1))
sdf_2 = (sdf.filter("record == 'OUT'").withColumnRenamed('date', 'date1')\
                                      .withColumnRenamed('type', 'type1')\
                                        .withColumnRenamed('name', 'name1')\
                                          .withColumn('ones', F.lit(1))
)

## partition it by id1 and id2 
windowSpec1 = Window.partitionBy("ID1","ID2").orderBy("date")
windowSpec2 = Window.partitionBy("ID1","ID2").orderBy("date1")

## creat a count column to count the number of 'IN' and 'OUT'
sdf_1 = (sdf_1.withColumn('counter', F.sum('ones').over(windowSpec1))\
              .drop("ones", "record")
        )
sdf_2 = (sdf_2.withColumn('counter', F.sum('ones').over(windowSpec2))\
               .withColumnRenamed('ID1','r_ID1')\
                 .withColumnRenamed('ID2','r_ID2')\
                   .withColumnRenamed('counter','r_counter')\
                     .drop("ones", "record")
         )
## merge the two dataframes back
sdf_merged = (sdf_1.join(sdf_2, ( sdf_1.ID1 == sdf_2.r_ID1) & 
                                        (sdf_1.ID2 == sdf_2.r_ID2)  & 
                                        (sdf_1.counter  == sdf_2.r_counter), 
                                        how ='left')\
                                .drop(sdf_2.r_ID1).drop(sdf_2.r_ID2).drop(sdf_2.r_counter).drop(sdf_1.counter)\
                                .orderBy(F.asc('date'))
             )
sdf_merged.show()

+-------+----+-------------------+--------+----------+-------------------+--------+----------+
|    ID1| ID2|               date|    type|      name|              date1|   type1|     name1|
+-------+----+-------------------+--------+----------+-------------------+--------+----------+
|ACC.PXP|7246|2020-02-24T14:49:00|    null|      null|2021-03-09T08:20:00|Hospital|Foundation|
|ACC.PXP|7246|2021-04-05T17:17:00|Hospital|Foundation|               null|    null|      null|
+-------+----+-------------------+--------+----------+-------------------+--------+----------+
```