# Equivalent of pandas merge_asof when joining spark dataframes, with merge nearest and tolerance

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, join, pyspark

I'm trying to replicate pandas's [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) behavior when joining Spark dataframes.

Let's just say I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`:

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{"timestamp": 0.5 * i, "a": i * 2} for i in range(66)])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{"timestamp": 0.33 * i, "b": i} for i in range(100)])

# use merge_asof to merge df1 and df2
merge_df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='timestamp', direction='nearest', tolerance=df.timestamp.diff().mean() - 1e-6)
```

Resulting `merge_df` would be:

| timestamp | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0.5 | 2 | 2 |
| 1.0 | 4 | 3 |
| 1.5 | 6 | 5 |
| 2.0 | 8 | 6 |
| ... | ... | .. |
| 30.5 | 122 | 92 |
| 31.0 | 124 | 94 |
| 31.5 | 126 | 95 |
| 32.0 | 128 | 97 |
| 32.5 | 130 | 98 |

Now given similar dataframes in Spark:

```
df1_spark = spark.createDataFrame([{"timestamp": 0.5 * i, "a": i * 2} for i in range(66)])
df2_spark = spark.createDataFrame([{"timestamp": 0.33 * i, "b": i} for i in range(100)])
```

How to join two Spark dataframes to produce similar result as in pandas, with configurable `direction` and `tolerance`?

[Edit]
As suggestion from similar posts, applying function over `Window` would create similar behavior to `direction` parameter. However, I still don't know how to apply function to find nearest row (like how `nearest` would behave) and within a certain range (`tolerance`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create merge\_asof functionality in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57435858/how-do-you-create-merge-asof-functionality-in-pyspark)

Comment: Although it's a good answer, It's still missing on how to reproduce behavior of nearest search with tolerance. I have updated my question and title to be more clearly. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What would be the size of df1 and df2? How many rows do you expect?

Comment: df1 and df2 are provided in the question; the number of rows of the output dataset should be the same as df1. I also believe the question can be decomposed in two parts: one with the `direction` parameter, and one with `tolerance`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following provides configurable `direction` and `tolerance` arguments. Window functions are used (`last` for "backward", `first` for "forward" and both of them for "nearest").

Also, in my experience, the `by` argument of Pandas' `merge_asof` is often needed. So I have made an effort to add this argument to the function too. The argument `by` would be beneficial, as it would further improve performance by creating partitions.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

def merge_asof(df_left, df_right, on: str, by=None, tolerance=None, direction: str='backward'):
    def backward():
        return add_diff(F.last(stru1, True).over(w0))
    def forward():
        return add_diff(F.first(stru1, True).over(w0.rowsBetween(0, W.unboundedFollowing)))
    def nearest():
        return F.array_sort(F.array(backward(), forward()))[0]
    def add_diff(col):
        return F.struct(
            F.abs(F.col(on) - col[on]).alias('diff'),
            col[on].alias(on),
            col[c].alias(c)
        )

    df_r = df_right if by else df_right.withColumn('_by', F.lit(1))
    df_l = df_left if by else df_left.withColumn('_by', F.lit(1))
    df_l = df_l.withColumn('_df_l', F.lit(True))
    by = [by] if isinstance(by, str) else by or ['_by']

    join_on = [on] + by
    df = df_l.join(df_r, join_on, 'full')

    w0 = W.partitionBy(*by).orderBy(on)
    for c in set(df_right.columns) - set(join_on):
        stru1 = F.when(~F.isnull(c), F.struct(on, c))
        stru2 = eval(f'{direction}()')
        if tolerance:
            stru2 = stru2.withField(c, F.when(stru2['diff'] <= tolerance, stru2[c]))
        df = df.withColumn(c, stru2[c])
    df = df.filter('_df_l').drop('_df_l', '_by')

    return df
```

**Some explanations**

First, function's arguments are being slightly modified, and full join is executed based on both, `on` and `by` arguments.

```py
df_r = df_right if by else df_right.withColumn('_by', F.lit(1))
df_l = df_left if by else df_left.withColumn('_by', F.lit(1))
df_l = df_l.withColumn('_df_l', F.lit(True))
by = [by] if isinstance(by, str) else by or ['_by']

join_on = [on] + by
df = df_l.join(df_r, join_on, 'full')
```

Then, for every column in the right dataframe (except for `on` and `by` columns), a new value is being calculated based on `direction` and `tolerance`.

```py
w0 = W.partitionBy(*by).orderBy(on)
for c in set(df_right.columns) - set(join_on):
    stru1 = F.when(~F.isnull(c), F.struct(on, c))
    stru2 = eval(f'{direction}()')
    if tolerance:
        stru2 = stru2.withField(c, F.when(stru2['diff'] <= tolerance, stru2[c]))
    df = df.withColumn(c, stru2[c])
```

`stru1` column (of *struct* type) is created, holding `on` and `c` values. `eval(f'{direction}()')` executes a function based on `direction`. Functions are created for every `direction` value ("backward", "forward", "nearest"). These functions add one more field ("diff") to the struct column. Then, if "diff" is above `tolerance` level, the value of the column is made `null`.

**Some examples**

```py
df1_spark = spark.createDataFrame([{"timestamp": 0.5 * i, "a": i * 2} for i in range(66)])
df2_spark = spark.createDataFrame([{"timestamp": 0.33 * i, "b": i} for i in range(100)])

merge_asof(df1_spark, df2_spark, on='timestamp', direction='backward').show(3)
# +---------+---+---+
# |timestamp|  a|  b|
# +---------+---+---+
# |      0.0|  0|  0|
# |      0.5|  2|  1|
# |      1.0|  4|  3|
# +---------+---+---+

merge_asof(df1_spark, df2_spark, on='timestamp', direction='forward').show(3)
# +---------+---+---+
# |timestamp|  a|  b|
# +---------+---+---+
# |      0.0|  0|  0|
# |      0.5|  2|  2|
# |      1.0|  4|  4|
# +---------+---+---+

merge_asof(df1_spark, df2_spark, on='timestamp', direction='nearest').show(3)
# +---------+---+---+
# |timestamp|  a|  b|
# +---------+---+---+
# |      0.0|  0|  0|
# |      0.5|  2|  2|
# |      1.0|  4|  3|
# +---------+---+---+

merge_asof(df1_spark, df2_spark, on='timestamp', tolerance=0.05, direction='nearest').show()
# +---------+---+----+
# |timestamp|  a|   b|
# +---------+---+----+
# |      0.0|  0|   0|
# |      0.5|  2|null|
# |      1.0|  4|   3|
# |      1.5|  6|null|
# |      2.0|  8|   6|
# |      2.5| 10|null|
# |      3.0| 12|   9|
# |      3.5| 14|null|
# |      4.0| 16|  12|
# |      4.5| 18|null|
# |      5.0| 20|  15|
# |      5.5| 22|null|
# |      6.0| 24|null|
# |      6.5| 26|null|
# |      7.0| 28|null|
# |      7.5| 30|null|
# |      8.0| 32|null|
# |      8.5| 34|null|
# |      9.0| 36|null|
# |      9.5| 38|null|
# +---------+---+----+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I really like the explanations you included. As of now this seems the most comprehensive (in terms of functionalities) and performant answer, although I did not have the time to test it yet.

Comment: I'm already started using this function in one of my projects. So if you find any issue, please tell :)

Comment: As said in my previous comment, I choose this answer for the most comprehensive functionalities. Thanks again for taking the time to answer :)

Comment: You can add a functionality that filters out rows from the left dataframe that do not match any row in the right dataframe due to tolerance reasons: I guess it would be just a filter at the end when columns originally belonging to the right dataframe are null...?

Comment: This method does not seem to be able to handle timestamps, causing data type mismatch: `...data type mismatch: argument 1 requires numeric type, however,... is of interval day to second type.`. Fix this by setting the timestamp to unix_timestamp i.e. making the timestamp numeric.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent code using PySpark is:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# Calculate the mean difference of the timestamp column in df1
mean_diff = df1.select(F.mean(F.col('timestamp').cast('long') - F.lag(F.col('timestamp')).over(Window.orderBy('timestamp')).cast('long'))).first()[0]

# Join df1 and df2 on the nearest timestamp within the tolerance
merge_df = df1.join(df2, F.abs(F.col('df1.timestamp').cast('long') - F.col('df2.timestamp').cast('long')) <= mean_diff - 1e-6, 'left')
```

### Explanation

The pandas merge_asof function performs a left join on the nearest key column within a specified tolerance. It is useful for merging time series data that may have slightly different timestamps.

The PySpark equivalent of this function is not available as a built-in method, but it can be achieved using a combination of join, window, and functions.

The first step is to calculate the mean difference of the timestamp column in df1, which is the same as the tolerance parameter in pandas. This can be done using the lag function, which returns the value of the previous row in a window, and the mean function, which returns the average of a column.

The second step is to join df1 and df2 on the condition that the absolute difference between their timestamp columns is less than or equal to the mean difference minus a small epsilon (1e-6) to avoid rounding errors. This ensures that the join is performed on the nearest timestamp within the tolerance. The join type is left, which means that all rows from df1 are preserved and matched with the closest rows from df2.

### Examples

To illustrate how the PySpark code works, let us use some sample data frames:

```py
# Sample data frames
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
  (1, '2021-01-01 10:00:00'),
  (2, '2021-01-01 10:01:00'),
  (3, '2021-01-01 10:02:00'),
  (4, '2021-01-01 10:03:00'),
  (5, '2021-01-01 10:04:00')
], ['id', 'timestamp'])

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
  ('A', '2021-01-01 09:59:50'),
  ('B', '2021-01-01 10:00:30'),
  ('C', '2021-01-01 10:01:10'),
  ('D', '2021-01-01 10:01:50'),
  ('E', '2021-01-01 10:02:30'),
  ('F', '2021-01-01 10:03:10'),
  ('G', '2021-01-01 10:03:50'),
  ('H', '2021-01-01 10:04:30')
], ['name', 'timestamp'])

# Display the data frames
df1.show()
+---+-------------------+
| id|          timestamp|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|2021-01-01 10:00:00|
|  2|2021-01-01 10:01:00|
|  3|2021-01-01 10:02:00|
|  4|2021-01-01 10:03:00|
|  5|2021-01-01 10:04:00|
+---+-------------------+

df2.show()
+----+-------------------+
|name|          timestamp|
+----+-------------------+
|   A|2021-01-01 09:59:50|
|   B|2021-01-01 10:00:30|
|   C|2021-01-01 10:01:10|
|   D|2021-01-01 10:01:50|
|   E|2021-01-01 10:02:30|
|   F|2021-01-01 10:03:10|
|   G|2021-01-01 10:03:50|
|   H|2021-01-01 10:04:30|
+----+-------------------+
```

The pandas merge_asof function would produce the following output:

```py
# Convert the timestamp columns to datetime objects
df1['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['timestamp'])
df2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['timestamp'])

# Perform the merge_asof
merge_df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='timestamp', direction='nearest', tolerance=df1.timestamp.diff().mean() - 1e-6)

# Display the output
merge_df
   id           timestamp name
0   1 2021-01-01 10:00:00    B
1   2 2021-01-01 10:01:00    C
2   3 2021-01-01 10:02:00    E
3   4 2021-01-01 10:03:00    F
4   5 2021-01-01 10:04:00    G
```

The PySpark code would produce the same output:

```py
# Calculate the mean difference of the timestamp column in df1
mean_diff = df1.select(F.mean(F.col('timestamp').cast('long') - F.lag(F.col('timestamp')).over(Window.orderBy('timestamp')).cast('long'))).first()[0]

# Join df1 and df2 on the nearest timestamp within the tolerance
merge_df = df1.join(df2, F.abs(F.col('df1.timestamp').cast('long') - F.col('df2.timestamp').cast('long')) <= mean_diff - 1e-6, 'left')

# Display the output
merge_df.show()
+---+-------------------+----+-------------------+
| id|          timestamp|name|          timestamp|
+---+-------------------+----+-------------------+
|  1|2021-01-01 10:00:00|   B|2021-01-01 10:00:30|
|  2|2021-01-01 10:01:00|   C|2021-01-01 10:01:10|
|  3|2021-01-01 10:02:00|   E|2021-01-01 10:02:30|
|  4|2021-01-01 10:03:00|   F|2021-01-01 10:03:10|
|  5|2021-01-01 10:04:00|   G|2021-01-01 10:03:50|
+---+-------------------+----+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I really like the linearity of your code and the explanations you included. One question though: you only considered direction `nearest` instead of `backward` and `forward` too. Do you think they can be inserted in your logic?

Answer (score 2):

The following code mimics the main parts of [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```python
def merge_asof(df1: DataFrame, df2: DataFrame, on: str, direction: str, tolerance: float):
    df1r = df1.withColumnRenamed(on, on + "_1")
    df2r = df2.withColumnRenamed(on, on + "_2")

    ret = df1r.crossJoin(df2r) \
        .withColumn("diff", F.abs(df1r[on + "_1"] - df2r[on + "_2"])) \
        .filter(F.col("diff") <= tolerance)
    if( direction == ''):
        direction = 'backward'
    if( direction == 'backward' ):
        ret = ret.filter(df1r[on + "_1"] >= df2r[on + "_2"])
    if( direction == 'forward' ):
        ret = ret.filter(df1r[on + "_1"] <= df2r[on + "_2"])

    ret = ret.drop(on + "_2").withColumnRenamed(on + "_1", on)
    selCols = [c for c in ret.columns if c not in [on, "diff"]]
    selCols = [F.expr(f"min_by({c}, diff) as {c}") for c in selCols]

    ret = ret.groupBy(F.col(on)).agg(*selCols).cache()

    ret = ret.unionByName(df1.join(ret, [on], "left_anti"), allowMissingColumns=True)
    return ret
```

The code consists of four steps:

##### Step 1: Join the dataframes and check the tolerance

```python
df1r = df1.withColumnRenamed(on, on + "_1")
df2r = df2.withColumnRenamed(on, on + "_2")

ret = df1r.crossJoin(df2r) \
    .withColumn("diff", F.abs(df1r[on + "_1"] - df2r[on + "_2"])) \
    .filter(F.col("diff") <= tolerance)
```

The two dataframes are [cross joined](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crossJoin.html), the difference between the keys is calculated for each row and rows having a larger difference than given by `tolerance` are removed from the result.

##### Step 2: Check the direction

```python
if( direction == ''):
    direction = 'backward'
if( direction == 'backward' ):
    ret = ret.filter(df1r[on + "_1"] >= df2r[on + "_2"])
if( direction == 'forward' ):
    ret = ret.filter(df1r[on + "_1"] <= df2r[on + "_2"])
```

If a direction is given, remove all rows from the result that do not fulfil this criterium.

##### Step 3: Aggregate duplicate keys

```python
ret = ret.drop(on + "_2").withColumnRenamed(on + "_1", on)
selCols = [c for c in ret.columns if c not in [on, "diff"]]
selCols = [F.expr(f"min_by({c}, diff) as {c}") for c in selCols]
ret = ret.groupBy(F.col(on)).agg(*selCols).cache()
```

There might be more than one row left over for a single key. Take the row where the keys have the smallest difference using [groupBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy.html) and [min_by](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/sql/index.html#min_by) as aggregation function.

##### Step 4: Add missing keys

```python
ret = ret.unionByName(df1.join(ret, [on], "left_anti"), allowMissingColumns=True)
```

In step 1 or 2 a key from the first dataframe might have been removed completely from the result. To mimic the *left outer* part of `merge_asof` these keys are now added again.

**Remark**: this logic uses `crossJoin` so it might not be the fastest way to join two large dataframes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I really like the explanations you included. I understand that it probably won't be so efficient due to the cross join operation. I'll wait another couple of days to see if other answers are added before awarding the bounty