# How to write pandas' merge_asof equivalence in PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, window-functions

I am trying to write a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) of pandas in Spark.

Here is a sample example:

```py
from datetime import datetime
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (datetime(2019,2,3,13,30,0,23),"GOOG",720.5,720.93),
        (datetime(2019,2,3,13,30,0,23),"MSFT",51.95,51.96),
        (datetime(2019,2,3,13,30,0,20),"MSFT",51.97,51.98),
        (datetime(2019,2,3,13,30,0,41),"MSFT",51.99,52.0),
        (datetime(2019,2,3,13,30,0,48),"GOOG",720.5,720.93),
        (datetime(2019,2,3,13,30,0,49),"AAPL",97.99,98.01),
        (datetime(2019,2,3,13,30,0,72),"GOOG",720.5,720.88),
        (datetime(2019,2,3,13,30,0,75),"MSFT",52.1,52.03)
    ],
    ("time", "ticker", "bid", "ask")
)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (datetime(2019,2,3,13,30,0,23),"MSFT",51.95,75),
        (datetime(2019,2,3,13,30,0,38),"MSFT",51.95,155),
        (datetime(2019,2,3,13,30,0,48),"GOOG",720.77,100),
        (datetime(2019,2,3,13,30,0,48),"GOOG",720.92,100),
        (datetime(2019,2,3,13,30,0,48),"AAPL",98.0,100),
    ],
    ("time", "ticker", "price", "quantity")
)
```

**Python**

```py
d1 = df1.toPandas().sort_values("time", ascending=True)
d2 = df2.toPandas().sort_values("time", ascending=True)

pd.merge_asof(d2, d1, on='time', by='ticker')
```

Outputs:

```
                        time ticker   price  quantity     bid     ask
0 2019-02-03 13:30:00.000023   MSFT   51.95        75   51.95   51.96
1 2019-02-03 13:30:00.000038   MSFT   51.95       155   51.95   51.96
2 2019-02-03 13:30:00.000048   GOOG  720.77       100  720.50  720.93
3 2019-02-03 13:30:00.000048   GOOG  720.92       100  720.50  720.93
4 2019-02-03 13:30:00.000048   AAPL   98.00       100     NaN     NaN
```

**Using UDF in Spark**

```py
import pandas as pd
def asof_join(l, r):
      return pd.merge_asof(l, r, on="time", by="ticker")

df2.sort("time").groupby("ticker").cogroup(df1.sort("time").groupby("ticker")).applyInPandas(
  asof_join, schema="time timestamp, ticker string, price float,quantity int,bid float, ask float"
).show(10, False)
```

Output:

```
+--------------------------+------+------+--------+-----+------+
|time                      |ticker|price |quantity|bid  |ask   |
+--------------------------+------+------+--------+-----+------+
|2019-02-03 13:30:00.000048|AAPL  |98.0  |100     |null |null  |
|2019-02-03 13:30:00.000048|GOOG  |720.77|100     |720.5|720.93|
|2019-02-03 13:30:00.000048|GOOG  |720.92|100     |720.5|720.93|
|2019-02-03 13:30:00.000023|MSFT  |51.95 |75      |51.95|51.96 |
|2019-02-03 13:30:00.000038|MSFT  |51.95 |155     |51.95|51.96 |
+--------------------------+------+------+--------+-----+------+
```

**NOTE**

The UDF works and gives me the right results, but I wanted to know if there is a more efficient way to do in PySpark using window functions? I am processing large data and UDF is the bottleneck.

Comment: i think the UDF serving the purpose is cleaner (of course, UDFs have their drawbacks). note - `merge_asof` will look backward by default, not the nearest. *a messy way of doing it in spark would be a cross join on the times for every ticker and then select the records that are nearest to one another.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a more comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69911136#74280780) with configurable `on`, `by`, `tolerance` and `direction` clauses of `merge_asof`. This answer only covers the "backward" direction.

OP's question can be answered by first joining and then using `last` over window:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

df = df2.withColumn('_df_left', F.lit(True)) \
        .join(df1, ['time', 'ticker'], 'full')
w = W.partitionBy('ticker').orderBy('time')
for c in set(df1.columns) - {'time', 'ticker'}:
    df = df.withColumn(c, F.coalesce(c, F.last(c, True).over(w)))
df = df.filter('_df_left').drop('_df_left')

df.show(truncate=0)
# +--------------------------+------+------+--------+-----+------+
# |time                      |ticker|price |quantity|bid  |ask   |
# +--------------------------+------+------+--------+-----+------+
# |2019-02-03 13:30:00.000048|AAPL  |98.0  |100     |null |null  |
# |2019-02-03 13:30:00.000048|GOOG  |720.77|100     |720.5|720.93|
# |2019-02-03 13:30:00.000048|GOOG  |720.92|100     |720.5|720.93|
# |2019-02-03 13:30:00.000023|MSFT  |51.95 |75      |51.95|51.96 |
# |2019-02-03 13:30:00.000038|MSFT  |51.95 |155     |51.95|51.96 |
# +--------------------------+------+------+--------+-----+------+
```